# MySQL Join question

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-error-1064

I'm setting up a small system that keeps track of which person is assigned to a request.

My table structure looks like this:

Table: requests

- RequestID
- RequestDetails

Table:request_staff

- RequestID
- StaffUserID

Obviously *RequestID* is used to link to the two tables.

I want to select all requests for a staff member. My understanding is that a join would be the best method...

```
SELECT *
FROM `request_staff`,`requests`
WHERE 'RequestID'.`request_staff` = 'RequestID'.`requests`;
```

I'm getting an error message of:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`request_staff` = 'RequestID'.`requests`' at line 3

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ahh, I can't believe I missed that. Proof that looking at a screen for too long makes the brain fall asleep. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `request_staff`,`requests`
WHERE `request_staff`.'RequestID' = `requests`.'RequestID';
```

You had the field and table names reversed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM request_staff, requests
WHERE request_staff.RequestID = requests.RequestID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the fields/tables backwards in your where statement.  Should be request_staff.RequestID = requests.RequestID